# Appengine: upload data to different entity kind

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Say I have entity kind A, and I create another entity kind identical to kind A call kind B.
I downloaded the entity kind A using builk loader. I want to upload all entity kind A (I just downloaded) to
entity kind B in the datastore. Is this possible?

Basically I want to upload downloaded data to the different kind.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the bulk loader.